# An issue with deleting of new records after adding them via pushObjects

Tags: ember.js

I try to create 'loadMore' feature.

My code for action 'loadMore':

```
this.store.findQuery('user', {
  skip: _this.get('skipped'),
  limit: _this.get('limit'),
  sort: _this.get('sort')
}).then(function(newData) {
  _this.get('model').pushObjects(newData.get('content'));
  _this.set('model.meta.total', newData.get('meta.total'));
  _this.set('skipped', _this.get('skipped') + _this.get('limit'));
});
```

My action for removing

```
remove: function(item) {
  item.destroyRecord();
},
```

My template

```
{{#each model as |row|}}
<tr>
   <a {{action 'remove' row}}>remove</a>
</tr>
{{/each}}
<a {{action 'loadMore'}}>loadMore</a>
```

When I remove a row which initially loaded via route's model, my template is updated. But when I click on 'loadMore' and try to delete new records, they are deleted from models and from server (ajax works), but my template is not updated.

I use Ember 1.12.0

Why?